# Get the number of gsub substitutions in Ruby

Tags: ruby

[`gsub` returns](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-gsub) the string, or `nil`. Is there a way to have it return the number of replacements it has made?

Comment: According to the `gsub` documentation link you provided, it returns more than either a string or nil.

Comment: `gsub` returns a new string, whereas `gsub!` returns the (substituted) receiver or `nil`

Answer (score 6):

I can think of using `gsub` block like this:

```
count = 0
str.gsub(/pat/) { |a| count+=1; "replacement" }
```

Example:

```
str = "lets replace all s with S"
count = 0
str.gsub("s") { |a| count+=1; "S" }
count
#=> 2
```

Answer (score 3):

In Ruby [gsub](http://apidock.com/ruby/String/gsub) without second argument returns an `Enumerator` and you can use it:

```
str = 'your string'
new_str = str.gsub(/your/, 'my')
count = str.gsub(/your/).count
```

Comment: Note that this will execute `gsub` twice